# Mysql alternate week days

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table has the following columns

```
| customer_id | service_start_date |
```

I want to provide the service on alternate week days from the service start date (eg:- every other mondays, every other tuesdays etc..)

If the `service_start_date` is a monday, then the service will be delivered on every other mondays.

Is there any way to query the mysql table to get all `customer_id`s who needs service on a particular date?

Comment: Would it not be the same as adding 14 days to the `service_start_date`? So essentially the days between service start and current date should be divisible by 14.

Comment: how do check if the difference in dates is divisible by 14? in query?

Comment: Heres how to do it in SQL Server  you can find comprable functions in MySQL  - WHERE Service_Start_Date< ParticularDate AND DATEDIFF(day,Service_Start_Date, ParticularDate)%14 = 0

Comment: [MOD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) is the function you need to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM Table as t
WHERE MOD(DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), DATE(service_start_date)), 14) = 0
```

This is assuming that your `service_start_date` is always a weekday.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to Clami219s answer:

To get the customer(s) that need service *on a particular date* (as of your request), use

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM table_name
WHERE
   service_start_date <= NOW() AND
   WEEKDAY(service_start_date) = WEEKDAY('2014-06-25'); //whatever date you like to fetch
```